# PHP catching substring between delimiters

Tags: php

This is code I am using:

```
$arr = "@media and (min-width: 768px){ .add{color: black;} } "
. "@media screen and (min-width: 480px) { body { background-color: " 
. "lightgreen; } } "
. "@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { div { background-color: "
. "lightgreen; } ul{color: red;} } ";

$keywords = array('@media', '}}');
$parts  = preg_split('/(' . implode('|', $keywords) . ')/', $arr
      , null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($parts);
```

And this is my output:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => "" 
  [1] => "@media" 
  [2] => "and (min-width: 768px){ .add{color: black;} }" 
  [3] => "@media" 
  [4] => "screen and (min-width: 480px) { body { background-color: lightgreen; } }"
  [5] => "@media" 
  [6] => "screen and (max-width: 480px) { div { background-color: lightgreen; } ul{color: red;} }" 
)
```

But, I need this:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => 
  [1] => "@media and (min-width: 768px){ .add{color: black;} } "
  [2] => "@media screen and (min-width: 480px) { body { background-color: lightgreen; } } " 
  [3] => "@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { div { background-color: lightgreen; } ul{color: red;} } "
)
```

What is the proper way to get that?

EDITED:
Two delimiters are neccessary as array maybe won't be always same. So if there is this case:

```
  $arr = "@media and (min-width: 768px){ .add{color: black;} }"
   . " body{} @media screen and (min-width: 480px) { body "
   . "{ background-color: lightgreen; } } @media screen and "
   . "(max-width: 480px) { div { background-color: lightgreen; } "
   . "ul{color: red;} }";
```

Desired output would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "@media and (min-width: 768px){ .add{color: black;} } "
    [1] => "body{} "
    [2] => "@media screen and (min-width: 480px) { body { background-color: lightgreen; } } "
    [3] => "@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { div { background-color: lightgreen; } ul{color: red;} } "
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question! I have come up with two answers, the second one is a lot better.

#### Answer 1: Not clean, and very static.

**Note:** This solution will pretty much only work with the example given by OP. For a better solution, look at *answer 2*

I will come up with something else that is more adjustable and not as `static`. For now, it works. 
([**Demo here**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/50a521480f5dcd3ac05572c3e25a2a90aea5f22c))

```
<?php
$arr = "@media and (min-width: 768px){ .add{color: black;} }"
. " body{} @media screen and (min-width: 480px) { body "
. "{ background-color: lightgreen; } } @media screen and "
. "(max-width: 480px) { div { background-color: lightgreen; } "
. "ul{color: red;} }";

$keywords = array("@media","} body");
$parts  = preg_split('/((?<='.implode('|',$keywords).')|(?='.implode('|',$keywords).'))/', trim($arr), null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$staticsize = count($parts);
for($i = 0; $i < $staticsize; $i++){
    if(!($i&1)){
        $next = $i + 1;
        if(strpos($parts[$i], '}') !== false){
            $parts[$i] = trim(str_replace("}","",$parts[$i]));
        }
        $parts[$next] = $parts[$i].$parts[$next];
        unset($parts[$i]);
    }
}
$parts = array_values($parts);
print_r($parts);
?>
```

This will give you the desired output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => @media and (min-width: 768px){ .add{color: black;} 
    [1] => body{} 
    [2] => @media screen and (min-width: 480px) { body { background-color: lightgreen; } } 
    [3] => @media screen and (max-width: 480px) { div { background-color: lightgreen; } ul{color: red;} }
)
```

#### Answer 2: More code, more flexible.

Now the fact is that I have come up with something else, it's a function that looks to into the depth of the elements, in case of `@media` the styling in there is in 2nd degree, so will be within that. Here is the function: ([**Demo here**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/89b7d208f42a5e910feaad57b11c13bf07b9d1a7))

```
function split_depth($string){
    $keywords = array("{","}");
    $parts  = preg_split('/((?<='.implode('|',$keywords).')|(?='.implode('|',$keywords).'))/', trim($string), null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    $noname = [];
    foreach(array_keys($parts) as $key){
        if(empty(trim($parts[$key]))){
            unset($parts[$key]);
        }
    }
    $parts = array_values($parts);
    foreach(array_keys($parts) as $key){

        switch(trim($parts[$key])){
            case "{":
                if(!array_key_exists($key, $noname)){
                    $noname[$key] = "open";
                }
            break;
            case "}":
                if(!array_key_exists($key, $noname)){
                    $noname[$key] = "close";
                }
            break;
        }
    }
    $open = 0;
    $close = 1;
    $cache = -1;
    $numberscache = 0;
    $sections = [];
    foreach(array_keys($noname) as $keyname){
        $name = $noname[$keyname];
        if($name == "open"){
            $open++;
        }else{
            if($open != 0){
                if($close == $open){
                    $c = ($cache) + (pow($open,2));
                    array_push($sections, array("open"  => $numberscache,"close" => $keyname));
                    $cache = $c + 1;
                    $numberscache = $keyname + 1;
                    $open = 0;
                    $close = 0;
                }   
            }else{
                echo "Syntax error in your CSS";
            }
            $close++;
        }
    }
    $parts = array_values($parts);
    $names = 0;
    $output = [];
    foreach($sections as $section){
        $name = "part".$names;
        $howmuch = ($section["close"] + 1) - $section["open"];
        $$name = trim(implode("",array_slice($parts,$section["open"],$howmuch)));
        array_push($output,$$name);
        $names++;
    }
    return $output;
}
```

The usage of this function:

```
$arr = "@media and (min-width: 768px){ .add{color: black;} }"
. " body{} @media screen and (min-width: 480px) { body "
. "{ background-color: lightgreen; } } @media screen and "
. "(max-width: 480px) { div { background-color: lightgreen; } "
. "ul{color: red;} }";
print_r(split_depth($arr));
```

As easy as that, it will output exactly the same, but now it will work with any css.

Comment: Yes, but it is neccessary to split with two delimeters, so the second one is }}. In case if $arr is different, and has for example body { background-color: lightgreen; } between two @media

Comment: Oh ok, I did not know that was a desire as well. In your * I need this* you also don't seperate it, I just went for the result you wanted. I have updated my answer. I hvae now added that future, although I don't know what behavior you want to change with that.

Comment: I have edited question as I can not put in comment array with multiple @. I realized few minutes ago that I am not separating it on second delimiter in my code also. Do you know how could I separate it to get desired output I edited above?

Comment: @codexy I have edited my answer, this time I have added a flexible version. It will take any css and turn it into your wanted result. I hope this has answered your question, if not, please ask. If solved, check as solved.